# Retornar um novo objeto usando a função ForEach

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenha a seguinte lista 
`List<EmployeeTotal> totals = Context.Database.SqlQuery<EmployeeTotal>(query).ToList();`

Quero transformar todos os objetos da lista `totals` em uma nova lista do tipo 
      `List<EmployeeTotalAdapter> totalsAdapter;`
para essa conversão eu utilizo o proprio construtor da classe `EmployeeTotalAdapter` recebendo um objeto do tipo `EmployeeTotal`

Estava pensando em utilizar o foreach com lambda para ir adicionando e gerando as conversões

```
  List<EmployeeTotalAdapter> totalsAdapter = new List<EmployeeTotalAdapter>(); 
  totalsAdapter.Add(totals.ForEach(t => new EmployeeTotalAdapter(t)));
```

Porem nao funciona informa;
Argument1: cannot convert from void to EmployeeTotalAdapter

é possível fazer algo assim ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A instrução tá ao contrário.

O certo seria:

> para cada elemento de `totals`, de nome `t`. Adicione um novo elemento em `totalsAdapter`.

```
totals.ForEach(t => totalsAdapter.Add(new EmployeeTotalAdapter(t)));
```

Também é possível fazer algo com LINQ

```
var totalsAdapter = totals.Select(t => new EmployeeTotalAdapter(t)).ToList();
```

Comment: Me falaram que a ordem dos fatores não alterava o resultado hehehe, assim que liberar eu aceito a resposta muito obrigado

Comment: hahaha neste caso faz uma diferença sim. Tranquilo XD